# Binary Search Tree, In Order Traversal, Step 3 logical assistance

Tags: c++, binary-tree, traversal

This isn't a request for a coding solution or compiler error. I'm more so trying to understand something.

I have been learning C++ for awhile now but I'm still in someways new. I'm following Paul's Programming Tutorials on youtube as well as other tutorials.

He has done a youtube video on the concept of an in order traversal of a binary search tree, and a youtube video showing the actual programming behind such a traversal.

If anyone can help me, I don't understand step 3.

My example program compiles and works fine and prints exactly as Paul's does. I got it working and can replicate it / likely reverse engineer it for purposes other than printing, but I want to actually understand it before just moving on.

This is the code of Paul's print function

```
void BinarySearchTree::printInOrderPrivate(node* Ptr)
{
    if(root_ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(Ptr->left_ptr != NULL)
        {
            printInOrderPrivate(Ptr->left_ptr);
        }
        cout << Ptr->key <<" ";//Process Node here

        if(Ptr->right_ptr != NULL)
        {
            printInOrderPrivate(Ptr->right_ptr);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"The tree is empty\n";
    }
}
```

I just don't see how it works logically. I will link his concept video, you don't need to watch it though, just pause it and see the diagram he made. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCXgWg5OfhY

On some nodes, like 3,  both the left **AND** right ptr will be pointing to NULL.

Note in the code that the recursive calls `PrintInOrderPrivate(Ptr->Left)` and `PrintInOrderPrivate(Ptr->Right)` are enclosed within if statements that require the Ptr's `->left` and `->right` to be a value other than NULL.

I see and understand how the algorithm works on paper, but how does the function not break at numbers like 3 wherein both left and right are null? How does it just know to go back?

And even assuming it did somehow just know to go back to the node containing 2, shouldn't it go right back down to 3?

(1)Node containing 2 has no left pointer
(2) print value
(3)  go right 
(right means go back to 3 again shouldn't it? This would loop).

I mean it works and I'm seeing it compile right in front of me but I can't wrap my head around how it's compiling. I maybe not even able to word the question right though but any help is appreciated. Thank you and excuse the tl;dr if your still here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of how to understand recursions is to think of a stack where each stack frame corresponds to a function call. Suppose you have the functions func1, func2 and func3. func1 calls func2 and func2 calls func3. The purpose of a stack now is to keep track of the point where func3 returns control to func2 and func2 to func1, respectively. When func1 is called the first stack frame is generated (lets call it f1). When func2 is called inside of func1 a second frame f2 is put on top of f1. And when func3 is called inside func2 a third frame is put on top of f2. A stack frame is popped off the stack when the corresponding function finished its tasks and returns control back to the function from where it was called. Thus, the orded the frames are popped off the stack is: first f3 then f2 and finally f1.

Analogically the function calls within a recursion are managed with a stack structure. Loosely speaking, when traversing a tree recursively each node is accessed by a function call in its adult node. Therefore, for each node there exists a corresponding frame on a stack. Hence, the reason why the algorithm doesn't terminate after encountering a node where both child nodes equal NULL is because of the stack. When a function finishes after leaving the else section of your code it is popped off the stack and control is returned to the stack frame beneath it.